# university logo in top right corner of every slide except the title page in beamer

Tags: beamer

Several similar questions have been asked already, but nothing seems to work for me.

What is an easy command that puts my university logo (I have it saved as an image on my pc) in the top right corner of every slide except to title page? I am working in beamer.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have seen similar questions, you will have seen 'MWE's too ;-) And that's what users appreciate highly here to start with ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Try below example:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{pgf}
\logo{\pgfputat{\pgfxy(0,8)}{\pgfbox[right,base]{\includegraphics[height=1cm]{logo.pdf}}}}
\newcommand{\nologo}{\setbeamertemplate{logo}{}}

\begin{document}
{
\nologo 
\begin{frame}[t]{Hello world}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{frame}[t]{Hello world}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\begin{frame}[t]{Hello world}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Item 1
        \item Item 2
        \item Item 3
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using plain title slide.
It worked for me.

Just use

```
\frame[plain]{\titlepage}
```

Comment: The problem even with `plain` is that there may be theme-dependent changes that would show the logo on that slide too. The OP does not contain any details.