# Beamer frame with picture and quote

Tags: beamer, graphics, templates

I would like a frame template with an image in the right bottom corner and some text to the left of it. How could I achieve this?

Here's a picture of what I had in mind.

[image: Desired frame]

The presentation code comes from the **Beamer Manual** (1.3. Euclid's presentation).

There is an option to add a picture to the bottom right of each slide. However, it's always the same picture, as it's thought for university logos.

**MWE *without* the picture and quote, as those were added with GIMP *after* generating the frame.**

```
% From the beamer manual. 

\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  % or ...

  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  % or whatever (possibly just delete it)
}


\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\title[] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{There is no largest prime number}

\subtitle
{A no-nonsense self-contained guide.} % (optional)

\author[Euclides]{Euclides of Alexandria \\ \texttt{euclides@sophomail.ax}}
%%%%%{F.~Author\inst{1} \and S.~Another\inst{2}}
% - Use the \inst{?} command only if the authors have different
%   affiliation.



\date[Short Occasion] % (optional)
{2017-01-15 / Informal gathering}

\subject{Index Funds and Efficient Investing}
% This is only inserted into the PDF information catalog. Can be left
% out. 



% If you have a file called "university-logo-filename.xxx", where xxx
% is a graphic format that can be processed by latex or pdflatex,
% resp., then you can add a logo as follows:

% \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.5cm]{university-logo}{university-logo.png}
% \logo{\pgfuseimage{university-logo}}



% Delete this, if you do not want the table of contents to pop up at
% the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}


\section{Motivation}

\subsection[Short First Subsection Name]{First Subsection Name}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a MWE?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228872/university-logo-in-top-right-corner-of-every-slide-except-the-title-page-in-beam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution: just borrow the logo layer to place you quote:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}

\begin{document}

{
    \logo{%
        \usebeamercolor*[fg]{normal text}
        \small 
        \begin{minipage}[b]{3cm}
            If we knew what it was we were doing, it would not be called research, would it? -- Albert Einstein
        \end{minipage}\quad\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}
    }
    \begin{frame}
        bla
    \end{frame}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Just a note to save some minutes of testing. `\begin{minipage}[b]{3cm}` Changing the *3* changes the width of the *text box* while doing so in the `\end{minipage}\quad\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}` line, modifies the width of the picture. Tweaking that is easy to get what I wanted. Thanks a lot!